# Android Wear - Integer ArrayList in Extra comes null

Tags: android, arraylist, wear-os

I'm with an issue that I don't know why it's happening.

I send a notification from handheld device to wearable to know when it has to open an activity.

From the handheld device, I send an ArrayList of Integer values:

```
dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putIntegerArrayList("SELECTED_RISKS", this.selectedRisks);
```

In the method "onDataChange" in WearableListenerService implementation, in my Wear App, I get the values this way:

```
ArrayList<Integer> risksSelected = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getIntegerArrayList("SELECTED_RISKS");
```

This works. The ArrayList is not null. Then, I put that ArrayList in the "Extras", set them to the Intent and show the Notification in the Wearable:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putIntegerArrayList("SELECTED_RISKS", risksSelected);
viewIntent.putExtras(extras);
PendingIntent pendingViewIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);
...
```

This also works. I can see in the debugger that the Extras are saving the ArrayList. But the problem comes here.

When I try to load the extras in "MainActivity":

```
if(extras.containsKey("SELECTED_RISKS") && extras.getIntegerArrayList("SELECTED_RISKS")!=null)
```

The bundle has the key "SELECTED_RISKS", but its value is null.

I don't know why this is happening, can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to how `PendingIntent` works. It's a common problem that extras get lost when using `PendingIntent`. If you already set a `PendingIntent` with a certain intent before and now you set it again with the only difference being extras, the old intent will be used.

Take a look a documentation of [`PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). Specifically you might try using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to force new extras.